# join condition with or

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracleforms

i have a form which contains
two database blocks  A and  B.
they are related by master detail (join) condition:
A.account=B.account

account is a type varchar2(10).
it works fine.
but the problem is that column (account )in
table B may contain data of length(5) which equal another column in table A called (subacc).

how to fetch all data as the below conditions:
A.account=B.account or A.subacc=B.account

Comment: Can those three columns have NULL values ..?

Comment: no they can't be null

Answer (score 1):

You need such a join condition, in which each paranthesed terms are mutually exclusive, should be added to the **Relations** node of **Master Data Block** :

```
 ( A.account=B.account AND LENGTH(B.account)>5 ) 
  OR ( A.subacc=B.account AND LENGTH(B.account)<=5 )
```

As all those columns have not NULL values, then no extra condition is needed to filter out whether any of the columns is NULL.

Comment: where to write the condition ? and shall i delete master detail relationship or to keep it

Comment: should be added to the Relations node of Master Data Block @user11161741